# Arc | Mutually exclusive relationship in workbench model

Tags: database-design, relational-database, mysql-workbench

I am currently making an assignment from a book called "Database ontwerp en implementatie" it is about oracle databases in workbench.

I have to make an arc relationship / mutually exclusive relationship / exclusive or relationship.

I have a Person entity/table and i have salesperson entity/table and a customer entity/table

A person can be only 1 of them but has to be one of them. How do i do this in mysql workbench?